# Where are the git credentials stored after cloning private repository | windows 10

Tags: git, powershell, github, git-credential-manager

This: [Where the git clone passwords are being stored or cached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616903/where-the-git-clone-passwords-are-being-stored-or-cached) is basically the question I have but it's unanswered.

If I clone a private repository from my github account via https, i get asked for username and password once. And then never ever again. I looked up in my local .git folder if I can found any password in plain text but I can't find any. I also looked in my windows User folder for the .git-credential, there is none. In my home folder is also no .config/git folder. I search everywhere but I don't know where the credentials are stored. If i push my commits of the repo to the server, it will just do it without asking me for password.

I am using windows 10
and git version 2.24.1.windows.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The credentials are stored in `windows credentials`.

Click on `start` > `control panel` > search for `windows credentials` > `manage your credentials`.

Over there the credentials used for git can be found.